# Can't stub a ReadOnly property twice?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have the following code. I have a somewhat legitimate reason for stubbing that property twice (See explanation below). It looks like it's only letting me stub it once.

```
private IStatus _status;

[SetUp()]
public void Setup() {
  this._status = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IStatus>();
  this._status.Stub(x => x.Connected()).Return(true);
  // This next line would usually be in the Setup for a subclass
  this._status.Stub(x => x.Connected()).Return(false);
}

[Test()]
public void TestTheTestFramework() {
  Assert.IsFalse(this._status.Connected()); // Fails...
}

public interface IStatus {
  bool Connected { get; }
}
```

I tried downloading the most recent [build](http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/Rhino-Mocks) (3.6 build 21), but still have the same issue. Any ideas on why I can't do this? I tried changing the `Connected` property on `IStatus` to be a function and the test still failed. I get the same behavior in VB.Net... Bug?

**Explanation on the double-stubbing**

I'm structuring my tests around inheritance. That way I can do common setup code just once, using injected mocked dependencies to simulate different conditions. I might provide a base/default stubbed value (e.g. yes, we're connected) which I'd want to override in the subclass that tests the behavior of the SUT when the connection is down. I usually end up with code like this.

```
[TestFixture()]
public class WhenPublishingAMessage {

  // Common setup, inject SUT with mocked dependencies, etc...

  [Test()]
  public void ShouldAlwaysWriteLogMessage {
    //Example of test that would pass for any sub-condition
  }

  [TestFixture()]
  public class AndNoConnection : WhenPublishingAMessage {
    // Do any additional setup, stub dependencies to simulate no connection
    // Run tests for this condition
  }

  [TestFixture()]
  public class AndHaveConnection : WhenPublishingAMessage {
    // Do any additional setup and run tests for this condition
  }
}
```

**Edit**

This [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/RhinoMocks/cJcF_EAjrb8/jU7NKZm_ZLgJ) on the Rhino Mocks google group might be helpful. It looks like I might need to call `this._status.BackToRecord();` to reset the state, so to speak... also, tacking on `.Repeat.Any()` to the second stub statement seemed to help as well. I'll have to post more details later.

Comment: For a better understanding of `.Repeat.*()` functionality, check out this blog post: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/05/04/rhino-mocks-recursion-and-multiple-return-values-from-stubs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum everything up, there's a three different answers that are possible:

#### Tallmaris's answer:

Specify a specific number of times to return on the first stub using `.Repeat.Times(n)`, `.Repeat.Once()`, `.Repeat.Twice()`, etc. For example:

`this._status.Stub(x => x.Connected()).Return(true).Repeat.Once();`
   `this._status.Stub(x => x.Connected()).Return(false);`

This method works pretty well if I know the number of times the stub will get called before I change it's behavior (e.g. it just gets called once in the constructor).

#### Reset the mocked object

I don't like this method since I'd like to avoid the (at least to me) more cumbersome Expect/Verify Record/Replay type syntax. It was recommending to me in [response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/RhinoMocks/Kfio_v-8Fbs/hUD1oonKI34J) to a post I made to the Rhino Mocks Google group with the same title as this question.

```
this._status.Stub(x => x.Connected).Return(true);

this._status.GetMockRepository().BackToRecordAll();
this._status.GetMockRepository().ReplayAll();

this._status.Stub(x => x.Connected).Return(false);
```

#### Using the magical Repeat.Any

I found that using `.Repeat.Any()` on the second stub overrode the first one work... I feel a bit bad adding some extra 'magic' code to make it work, but in the case where you don't know how often to tell the first stub to return, this option will work.

```
this._status.Stub(x => x.Connected()).Return(true);
this._status.Stub(x => x.Connected()).Return(false).Repeat.Any();
```

Note: you can't do `.Repeat.Any()` more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify .Repeat.Once() on the first result so that it will be used once and then the next one, as explained in this other [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609589/ordering-method-return-values-with-rhino-mock-stubs)

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work particularly well, since I'd like it to return the same result multiple times in the tests of other subclasses, I just want to override that behavior in this particular subclass.

Comment: If you have the need for different behaviours you will need to move the initialization code inside the proper test and maybe leave in the Setup the part that is common to every one. You can also have a setup method with a parameter and call it manually from every test passing the number of times you want to return the first result before returning the second...