# Unit tests for ServiceStack services

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq, servicestack

I am trying to write simple unit test for ServiceStack service, I am going through tests they've online and few threads here. This is the main thread that has most details I am trying to accomplish - [Unit Test HTTPRequest Headers with ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790695/unit-test-httprequest-headers-with-servicestack/14791657).

However, I am facing problems injecting IDbConnection object into the service. In the webmethod, a dictionary object is populated by using OrmLite's GetDictionary method. But I am unable to mock it since GetDictionary is extension method.

```
 private Mock<IDbConnection> _dbConnectionMock;
 private Dictionary<string, string> _nameValuePairs;

 [SetUp]
 public void SetUp()
 {
    _dbConnectionMock = new Mock<IDbConnection>();

    _nameValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
            {"name","test"},
            {"Updatedby",   "5/23/12 7:00:15 AM"},
            {"Address", "212 Adam St."}
    };
}
```

In test method

```
 var service = new CustomerLookupService(_dbConnectionMock.Object);
 var response = (HttpResult)service.Any(new CustomerLookup { name = "test" });
 //assert statements
```

If GetDictionary method cannot be mocked, I am even willing to call web method that hits DB, for this do I need to create AppHost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple of options to look into.

- Mocking/stubbing/unit-testing extension methods [here](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-extension-methods-ruined-unit-testing-and-oop-and-a-way-forward/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq) or various other spots. I don't think there is a preferred way to do this but there are some options and frameworks/libraries to help.
- Running an in memory database such as Sqlite for your unit tests. See [here](http://rickardnilsson.net/post/2013/01/19/how-to-unit-test-your-database-code-when-using-servicestack-ormlite.aspx).
- You could abstract the IDConnection into a CustomerLookUpRepository and inject your CustomerLookUpRepository into your service. Then you can just mock your 'Repository'.

I've given this 'arrangement' a try. So far it seems to work for most basic cases. The data access pattern is taking from the [Redis Web Service example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.RedisWebServices). YMMV, though.

**Test** (using RhinoMocks)

```
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var _nameValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"name","test"},
            {"Updatedby",   "5/23/12 7:00:15 AM"},
            {"Address", "212 Adam St."}
        };

        var mockSqlRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISqlRepository>();
        mockSqlRepository.Stub(
            x => x.Exec(Arg<Func<IDbConnection, Dictionary<string, string>>>.Is.NotNull)).Return(_nameValuePairs);

        var service = new CustomerLookupService { SqlRepository = mockSqlRepository }
        //MORE TEST CODE...  
    }
```

**Service class** - using ISqlRepository to abstract/hide IDbConnection. ISqlRepository has a function that takes a function as the parameter. The function signature (of the parameter) takes IDbConnection as a parameter so I don't have to write several methods to access the database.

```
public class CustomerLookupService
{
    public ISqlRepository SqlRepository { get; set; }

    public void Any(CustomerLookup request)
    {
        var results =
            SqlExec<Dictionary<string, string>>((con) => con.GetDictionary<type, type>("Select id, name from table"));
        //MORE SERVICE CODE
    }

    public T SqlExec<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> fn)
    {
        return SqlRepository.Exec(fn);
    }
}
```

**ISqlRepository**

```
public interface ISqlRepository
{
    T Exec<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> fn);
}
```

**SqlRepository**

```
public class SqlRepository : ISqlRepository
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    public T Exec<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> fn)
    {
        using (var con = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            return fn(con);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. I've a doubt, if we have multiple read operations that retrieve dictionaries in the method, how to mock those in the test. Do we need to mention mock objects in the same order.

Comment: This solution probably isn't the best if you're testing a method that will do many database operations and each return the same Type. Might be able to achieve return differnt values based on the 'calling order' using Rhino Mocks - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609589/ordering-method-return-values-with-rhino-mock-stubs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know any alternative ideas for multiple database operations. Fact that I like this method is I don't need to create individual repositories by violating DRY principle.